# How to verify day of the week to show / hide content

Tags: if-statement, twig

I'm a bit stuck here and making it too complex in my head :-D

[SOLUTION]
DarkBee gave me the working solution, but unfortunately I can't up vote his answer. Thank you all very much for thinking with me!
[/SOLUTION]

**What I'd like to achieve and the current situation**

I have a page, let's say product.twig which includes a countdown timer file (i.e. countdown.twig) which loads a JS script with the actual functionality.

I want to hide the countdown timer on specific days of the week (saturday & sunday), and instead show a custom text. I could make this work in JS, but this needs to run the script, which causes unnecessary load. The most efficiënt way would be to verify which day of the week it is in TWIG, so everything is done by the server, by not loading the countdown page, and thus not loading the actual JS file.

Can this be done with an IF statement? IF day = saturday (or 6 / 7) text: Delivered tuesday ELSE include countdown.twig

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Darkbee's solution works like a charm! Tweaked it a bit to make it even more efficient. As the countdown timer isn't needed on Saturday & Sunday, I don't need the ELSE statement. Instead I changed the `IF` in `IF NOT` (`{% if "now"|date('N') not in [ 0, 7, ] %}`)

```
{% if "now"|date('N') not in [ 0, 7, ] %}
    <div class="countdowner mt-3 d-flex align-items-center">
        <span class="h4 mb-0">Morgen in huis?</span><span style="padding-top: 4px;" class="px-2"> Je hebt nog:</span>
        <span style="background-color: #547A82; color: white; border-radius: 4px; width: 75px;" class="text-center h4 m-0 p-1 px-2 timeleft" id="countdownTimer"></span>
    </div>
<script src="{{ 'countdowner.js.rain' | url_asset }}"></script>
{% endif %}
```

For the ones staring at the extension of countdowner.js.rain: It's Lightspeed HQ's framework which is based on TWIG / DRAFT

Answer (score 0):

You can just use the [`date`](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/3.x/filters/date.html) filter along with `"now"` to get the current date

```
{% if "now"|date('N') in [ 6, 7, ] %}
    Delivered tuesday
{% else %}
    {% include "countdown.twig" %}
{% endif %}
```

[demo](https://twigfiddle.com/dt2abq)

Comment: You're my hero @DarkBee! I included your solution in my topic also, for folks ending up at this topic when they're searching for a solution :-)

Comment: would this also be possible with time? Let's say that I want it hidden if the set end-time is passed, but still the same day. I set the max to 22:00, but there are still 2 hours on that day left

Comment: Solved for the time with this line of code:
{% if "now"|date('N') not in [ 0, 7, ] and "now"|date('G') < 22 %}